# why wont this bootstrap drop down menu work in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to Rails and I have looked for the answer to this question all over web. I tried many different solutions, but none of them seemed to work.Here is what I have.

In my Header:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"> 
  <div class="navbar-inner"> 
    <div class="container"> 
      <%= link_to "Example App", root_path, id: "logo" %> 
      <nav> 
        <ul class="nav pull-right"> 
          <li> <%= link_to "Home", root_path %> </li> 
          <li> <%= link_to "Help", help_path %> </li> 
          <% if signed_in? %> 
            <li> <%= link_to "Users", '#' %> </li> 
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown"> 
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
                Account <b class="caret"></b> 
              </a> 
              <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                <li> <%= link_to "Profile", current_user %> </li> 
                <li> <%= link_to "Settings", '#' %> </li> 
                <li class="divider"></li> 
                <li> 
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %> 
                </li> 
              </ul> 
            </li> 
          <% else   %> 
            <li> <%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %> </li> 
          <% end  %> 
        </ul> 

      </nav> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
</header>

 My applications.js File:
    //= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this code to your page.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

This will load the application.js file and all the files it requires.

Comment: then it must be one of the reasons Kristian listed below

Answer (score 0):

Rails is not responsible for what is written *inside* of your javascript, so the only possible problems with something like a twitter bootstrap functionality not working is the following two conditions:

1. you didn't write the correct markup for bootstrap, or
2. you didn't include the javascript required for it to run.

as Derek_duncan said, you can include your rails javascript tag: `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

Using that method, you're assuming the bootstrap.[min.]js file is actually in your /assets/js/ directory and that you're set to load all JS assets no matter what. if you set it up differently, then you'd have to actually include the JS tag specifically.